# javascript append elements into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I build this looping animation with dynamic words but I need to append all the span into the div  `<div id"wordcloud"></div>`. I can't get it done as I want so I need a bit of help here.

```js
var interval = 100;
var width = 800;
var height = 500;

var words = [
  'Liberty',
  'Morality',
  'Modesty',
  'Curiosity',
  'Imagination',
  'Excitement',
  'Structure',
  'Intellect',
  'Friendliness',
  'Conversation'
];
var wordPlacementInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var currentWord = words.shift();
  if (currentWord) {


    var word = document.createElement('span');

    word.innerHTML = currentWord;
    word.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1) + 'px';
    word.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1) + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(word);
  } else {
    clearInterval(wordPlacementInterval);
  }
}, interval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wordcloud"></div>
```

Comment: How do you want to do it? Could you explain?

Comment: As @dloeda mentions, it's unclear what the expected result should be. Could you add an example of the expected output to your question?

Comment: Instead of `document.body` use `document.getElementById('wordcloud')`?

Comment: Strange. You include jQuery, but never use it.

Comment: Looks like they are appending to me.... what is wrong exactly? My guess is the fact you are missing style="position: absolute" or realtive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a missing `=` in the id property `<div id[HERE]"wordcloud"></div>`

and then add the elements you create to

```
document.querySelector('#wordcloud').appendChild(word);
```

like so:

```js
var interval = 100;
var width = 800;
var height = 500;

var words = [
  'Liberty',
  'Morality',
  'Modesty',
  'Curiosity',
  'Imagination',
  'Excitement',
  'Structure',
  'Intellect',
  'Friendliness',
  'Conversation'
];
var wordPlacementInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var currentWord = words.shift();
  if (currentWord) {


    var word = document.createElement('span');

    word.innerHTML = currentWord;
    word.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1) + 'px';
    word.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1) + 'px';
    document.querySelector('#wordcloud').appendChild(word);
  } else {
    clearInterval(wordPlacementInterval);
  }
}, interval);
```

```html
<div id="wordcloud"></div>
```

If you are trying to use the positions you are setting via javascript you need to add little CSS like:

```js
var interval = 100;
var width = 800;
var height = 500;

var words = [
  'Liberty',
  'Morality',
  'Modesty',
  'Curiosity',
  'Imagination',
  'Excitement',
  'Structure',
  'Intellect',
  'Friendliness',
  'Conversation'
];
var wordPlacementInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var currentWord = words.shift();
  if (currentWord) {


    var word = document.createElement('span');

    word.innerHTML = currentWord;
    word.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1) + 'px';
    word.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1) + 'px';
    document.querySelector('#wordcloud').appendChild(word);
  } else {
    clearInterval(wordPlacementInterval);
  }
}, interval);
```

```css
#wordcloud {
    position: relative;
}

#wordcloud span {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordcloud"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add CSS [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) `relative` to the `span` elements.

Code example:

```js
var interval = 100;
var width = 200;
var height = 150;
var words = ['Liberty', 'Morality', 'Modesty', 'Curiosity', 'Imagination', 'Excitement', 'Structure', 'Intellect', 'Friendliness', 'Conversation'];
var wordPlacementInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var currentWord = words.shift();
  var word = document.createElement('span');
  var wordcloud = document.getElementById('wordcloud');
  
  if (!currentWord) {
    clearInterval(wordPlacementInterval);
    return;
  }

  word.innerText = currentWord;
  word.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1) + 'px';
  word.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1) + 'px';
  wordcloud.appendChild(word);
}, interval);
```

```css
#wordcloud {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
span {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wordcloud"></div>
```

Answer (score -4):

I think this will help

```
$("#wordcloud").html(word)
```

Do this instead of the document.body.appendChild()

Comment: Each iteration will overwrite the previous.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the point, since it's an animation with words